# Verbatim alignment in XePersian

Tags: verbatim, xepersian

Verbatim environment is right-aligned when using XePersian package, so I have to wrap it in `latin` environment. So I decide to create a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{faverbatim}
{\begin{latin}‎‎\begin{verbatim}‎}
{‎\end{verbatim}‎‎\end{latin}‎ }
```

Unfortunately it generates an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` in arguments to other commands (in this case `\newenvironment`).

The package `\verbatim` allows to overcome this limitation:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newenvironment{faverbatim}
  {\latin\verbatim}
  {\endverbatim\endlatin}
```

Notice that the "internal" versions of the commands should be used.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain which commands can be used in \newenvironment and which one can't?

Comment: `\begin{verbatim}` is *the* exception, in general. However the situation is a bit different when using the `verbatim` package for defining a new verbatim environment; read the manual for the package: either do `texdoc verbatim` in a terminal window or [click here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/verbatim.pdf)